# PPPoEグローバルIP偽装について教えて下さい。

Tags: windows, http

PPPoEグローバルIP偽装について教えて下さい。

勉強目的で、
**グローバルIPを偽装してHTTPリクエストを送信し、かつ、

HTTPレスポンスを受信する方法を調べています。**

現時点で、以下の方法で可能かなと思っています。
・送信TCPパケットの送信元IPを任意のグローバルIPにする
・送信TCPパケットのソースルーティングに自ルータのグローバルIPを指定する
・自ルータのDMZ機能等を使用してWANからの受信TCPパケットをLANへ流す

**そこで、以下①②をご教授下さい。

片方だけでも構いません。**

**現在以下の構成です。

「クライアントPC←→自ルータ←→終端装置←→雲←→サーバ」**

**①グローバルIPを偽装する方法**
クライアントPCで発行する送信TCPパケットの送信元IPを任意のグローバルIPにすれば良いのでは？

と考えたのですが、よくよく考えるとこれは多分ダメで、

これはLAN内の話になってしまい、
いくらLAN内で偽装しても、WANから出ていく送信TCPパケットの送信元IPはPPPoEで割り当てられたグローバルIPになってしまって、
任意グローバルIPの偽装が出来ないのでは？と考えました。
※こちら合っていますか？

なので、クライアントPCで発行する送信TCPパケットではなく、
自ルータ君が何かしらの方法で任意のグローバルIPに偽装する必要があるのでは？と考えました。
※こちら合っていますか？

合っている場合、どのようにして任意のグローバルIPに偽装すればいいのでしょうか？
合っていない場合、何が合っていないかを教えて下さい。

**②PPPoEに縛られずに送受信を行う方法**

NTTの光フレッツでプロバイダを使用してます。
要はPPPoEです。

ここで以下サイトに「PPPoEなどを用いずにEthernetをそのままインターネットなどに接続することも技術的には可能」
とあります。
http://e-words.jp/w/PPPoE.html

PPPoEを使わずにインターネットに繋ぐってどういう方法でしょうか？
この方法を教えて下さい。
若者世代でPPPoEが当たり前なので、このPPPoE以外でインターネットに繋ぐ方法を知りません。

PPPoEだと、どうしてもプロバイダが発行するグローバルIPに縛られてしまい、
仮に偽装が出来てもプロバイダでブロックされてしまうので、
偽装が出来ないとでは？と考えている為です。

プロバイダに縛られない自由な環境があれば、
自由に偽装が可能なのでは？と考えているのです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9571918.html

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/dounatte/items/c94705335c448cc05b90

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10135

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/60356

Answer (score 3):

送信元IPアドレスを偽装したサーバーに接続した場合、サーバーからの応答は本来そのIPアドレスを使用している端末に対してルーティングされます。グローバルIPを使って例示する訳にはいかないので、あえてプライベートIPアドレスを使って説明します。

例えば貴方の端末が本来使用しているグローバルIPが192.168.1.2である場合に、IPアドレス192.168.2.1に偽装したパケットを送信したとします。この場合サーバーからの応答は192.168.2.1の端末が所属するネットワークに向かってルーティングされるので、貴方の端末では受信出来ません。

送信元IPアドレスを偽装する実験をしたいのであれば、グローバルネットワークではなく貴方の管理下のネットワーク内で完結するようにして実験されるのが良いと思います。

Comment: ソースルーティングを使った場合はどうでしょうか？

SSRRやLSRRを送信者が指定した場合、
１．それが適用されるのは送信経路においてでしょうか？

２．それとも返って来る途中の受信経路においてでしょうか？

３．それとも両方の経路でしょうか？

もし１.送信経路のみの場合、
偽装したIP当てに返信がいってしまうため、自分に返ってこないという認識で正しいでしょうか？

もしそうなら、偽装したIPを自分に返す方法は他にございますでしょうか？

Comment: 経路上のルーターでSSRRやLSRRが有効になっていれば可能でしょうけど、セキュリティ上の観点からグローバルネット上のルーターでは無効になっているのが普通です。偽装したIPを自分に返す方法は、グローバルネットに置いては無いと考えた方が良いです。